# Can't click on menu item when clicked on menu in portrait mode

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

When I click on the menu icon which is active below the 625px the menu in the width > 625 becomes unclickable. And when I reload the page and click on menu in large screen size the menu button in mobile devices becomes unclickable.

It must be some problem with the way jquery code is written. 
No errors are shown in the console.

It's a simple navigation with sub menu. `.dropli` is one menu item in navigation.
`.dropdown` is the drop down.

The `.menu-icon` is the anchor tag which opens the enitre navigation when clicked for mobile browsers

**Note:**
when I hover over the `.dropli` the `.menu-icon` becomes inactive. And when i reload and click on `.menu-icon`, `.dropli` becomes inactive

```js
$(document).ready(function() {  
    
      $(".dropli>a").on("mouseover", function() {
        $(".dropdown").show();
      });
      $(".dropli").on("mouseleave", function() {
        $(".dropdown").hide();
      });
      if ($(window).width() <= 625) {
        $(".dropli>a").on("mouseover", function() {
          $(".dropdown").show();
        });
        $(".dropli").on("mouseleave", function() {
          $(".dropdown").show();
        });
        $(".dropdown").show();
        // $(".nav").hide();
      } else {
        // $(".nav").show();
      }
    
      
    
      $(window).resize(function() {
        if ($(window).width() <= 625) {
          // $(".nav").hide();
          $(".dropdown").show();
          $(".dropli>a").on("mouseover", function() {
            $(".dropdown").show();
          });
          $(".dropli").on("mouseleave", function() {
            $(".dropdown").show();
          });
        } else {
          $(".dropdown").hide();
          // $(".nav").show();
          $(".dropli>a").on("mouseover", function() {
            $(".dropdown").show();
          });
          $(".dropli").on("mouseleave", function() {
            $(".dropdown").hide();
          });
          $(".dropli").on("click", function() {
            $(".drpodown").toggle();
            console.log('clicked');
          });
        }
        
      });
    
      function zin() {
        $(".nav").css("z-index", "1");
        $("nav").css("z-index", "1");
      }
      function zino() {
        $(".nav").css("z-index", "-1");
        $("nav").css("z-index", "-1");
      }
    
      function dropdown() {
        if ($(window).width() <= 625) {
          // $(".header nav").css("height", "0");
          $(".menu-icon").on("click", function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
             console.log('clicked');
            if ($("nav").height() < 5) {
              console.log($(".nav").height());
              $("nav").animate({ height: $(".nav").height() + 15 + "px" }, 750);
              // $(".nav").css("z-index", "1");
              // $("nav").css("z-index", "1");
              setTimeout(zin, 750);
            } else {
              $("nav").animate({ height: "0px" }, 750);
              zino();
            }
          });
        } else {
          $("nav").css("height", "auto");
        }
      }
      dropdown();
      $(window).resize(function() {
        if ($(window).width() > 625) {
          $("nav").css("height", "auto");
        } else {
          $("nav").css("height", "0");
        }
        console.log($(window).width());
      });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="header main-container">
          <div class="fb">
            <span class="fb-logo">Follow us on Facebook :</span>
            <img src="img/fb.png">
          </div>
          <a class="menu-icon">
            <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
          </a>
          <header>
            <div class="logo">
              <a href="index.html">
                <img src="img/logo.png" alt="keep it on logo">
              </a>
            </div>
          </header>
          <nav>
            <ul class="nav">
              <li class="dropli">
                <a>Menu</a>
                <ul class="dropdown">
                  <li>
                    <a href="#section1">Menu</a>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <a href="#section2">Menu</a>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <a href="#section3">Menu</a>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <a href="#section4">Menu</a>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <a href="#section5">Menu</a>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#">menu</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#">menu</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#">menu</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
            <!-- <div class="fb">
              <span class="fb-logo">Follow us on Facebook :</span>
              <img src="img/fb.png">
            </div> -->
          </nav>
        </section>
```

I tried a different approach but still didnt get the answer.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      // console.log($(window).width());
      // $(window).resize(function() {
      //   if ($(window).width() > 625) {
      //     $(".nav").show();
      //   } else {
      //     $(".nav").hide();
      //   }
      // });
      // code for dropdown in non mobile browsers
      // $(".dropli>a").on("mouseover", function() {
      //   $(".dropdown").show();
      // });
      // $(".dropli").on("mouseleave", function() {
      //   $(".dropdown").hide();
      // });
      // code for dropdown in mobile browsers
      // if ($(window).width() <= 625) {
      //   $(".dropli>a").on("mouseover", function() {
      //     $(".dropdown").show();
      //   });
      //   $(".dropli>a").on("mouseleave", function() {
      //     $(".dropdown").show();
      //   });
      //   $(".dropdown").show();
      //   // $(".nav").hide();
      // } else {
      //   // $(".nav").show();
      //   $(".dropli>a").on("mouseover", function() {
      //     $(".dropdown").show();
      //   });
      //   $(".dropli>a").on("mouseleave", function() {
      //     $(".dropdown").hide();
      //   });
      // }

      // $(window).resize(function() {
      //   $(".dropli>a").on("mouseover", function() {
      //     $(".dropdown").show();
      //   });
      //   $(".dropli").on("mouseleave", function() {
      //     $(".dropdown").hide();
      //   });
      //   if ($(window).width() <= 625) {
      //     $(".dropli>a").on("mouseover", function() {
      //       $(".dropdown").show();
      //     });
      //     $(".dropli").on("mouseleave", function() {
      //       $(".dropdown").show();
      //     });
      //     $(".dropdown").show();
      //     // $(".nav").hide();
      //   } else {
      //     // $(".nav").show();
      //   }
      // });

      // $(window).resize(function() {
      //   if ($(window).width() <= 625) {
      //     // $(".nav").hide();
      //     $(".dropdown").show();
      //     $(".dropli>a").on("mouseover", function() {
      //       $(".dropdown").show();
      //     });
      //     $(".dropli").on("mouseleave", function() {
      //       $(".dropdown").show();
      //     });
      //   } else {
      //     $(".dropdown").hide();
      //     // $(".nav").show();
      //     $(".dropli>a").on("mouseover", function() {
      //       $(".dropdown").show();
      //     });
      //     $(".dropli").on("mouseleave", function() {
      //       $(".dropdown").hide();
      //     });
      //     $(".dropli").on("click", function() {
      //       $(".drpodown").toggle();
      //       console.log('clicked');
      //     });
      //   }
      //   if ($(window).width() <= 625) {
      //     $(".menu-icon i").on("click", function(e) {
      //       e.preventDefault();

      //       if ($("nav").height() < 5) {
      //         console.log($(".nav").height());
      //         $("nav").animate({ height: $(".nav").height() + 15 + "px" }, 750);
      //       } else {
      //         $("nav").animate({ height: "0px" }, 750);
      //       }
      //     });
      //   }
      // });

      // function zin() {
      //   $(".nav").css("z-index", "1");
      //   $("nav").css("z-index", "1");
      // }
      function zino() {
        // if ($("nav").height() < 508) {
        // console.log("this worked in zion");
        // $(".nav").css("z-index", "-1");
        // $("nav").css("z-index", "-1");
        // }
        setTimeout(function() {
          if ($("nav").height() > 508) {
            $(".nav").css("z-index", "1");
            $("nav").css("z-index", "1");
            // console.log("this is working");
          } else {
            if ($("nav").height() < 508) {
              $(".nav").css("z-index", "-1");
              $("nav").css("z-index", "-1");
              // console.log("this is working fornow");
            }
          }
        }, 850);
      }
      // while ($("nav").height() > 508) {
      //   $(".nav").css("z-index", "1");
      //   $("nav").css("z-index", "1");
      // }
      // code for mobile menu
      function dropdown(a) {
        // $(".header nav").css("height", "0");
        $(".menu-icon i").on("click", function(e) {
          e.preventDefault();
          if ($(window).width() <= 626) {
            if ($("nav").height() < 5) {
              // console.log($(".nav").height());
              $("nav").animate(
                { height: $(".nav").height() + 15 + "px" },
                750,
                zino()
              );
              // $(".nav").css("z-index", "1");
              // $("nav").css("z-index", "1");

              // var currentHeight;
              // setTimeout(function(currentHeight) {
              //   currentHeight = $("nav").height();
              // }, 1000);
              // console.log(currentHeight);
            } else {
              if ($("nav").height() < 508) {
                $(".nav").css("z-index", "-1");
                $("nav").css("z-index", "-1");
                // console.log("this is working fornow from else");
              }
              $("nav").animate({ height: "0px" }, 750);
              // if ($("nav").height() < 508) {
              //   console.log("this is working now")
              //   zino();
              // }
              console.log($("nav").height());

              // if ($("nav").height() < currentHeight) {

              // } else {
              //   console.log("this thing ran");
              // }
            }
            console.log($("nav").height());
          } else {
            $("nav").css("height", "auto");
          }
          $(".nav").css("z-index", "-1");
          $("nav").css("z-index", "-1");
          // console.log("code for mobile menu");
          // console.log(a);
          //  console.log('clicked');
        });

        console.log(a);
      }
      dropdown();
      $(window).resize(function() {
        if ($(window).width() <= 625) {
          // dropdown("ran from resize");
        }
      });

      $(window).resize(function() {
        if ($(window).width() > 625) {
          // console.log("bottom code ran");
          $("nav").css("height", "auto");
        } else {
          $("nav").css("height", "0");
        }
        // console.log($(window).width());
      });
    });
```

html for the code

Comment: Have you checked(inspected) HTML so that no div or other element is over your element with the click functionality?

Comment: no there is none

Comment: can you add the html ?

Comment: @marcogomes added the html

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in your code

```
$(".drpodown").toggle();
```